# Serialize(): данные не сохраняются в базу

Tags: jquery, php

Всем добрый день. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Пишу небольшой проект на CakePhp, есть форма и кнопка сохранить, по нажатию на нее данные формы получаю методом `serialize()` и выполняю ajax запрос, но почему-то эти данные не хотят сохраняться в базу!

```
$("a img[id = 'save']").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).closest('tr').find('form').serialize();
    $.post("/Group/Players/save", {
        data: data
    }, function (success) {})
});
```

Контроллер Players

```
function save()
{
    $data    = $this->request->data;
    $pl_info = $this->Player->read(NULL, $data['id']);
    $this->Player->save($data);
    $this->redirect(array(
        'action' => 'admin'
    ));
}
```

Comment: console.log(data);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С CakePhp не знаком, но `{data:data}` неправильно, пишите просто `data` тогда PHP скрипту придет `$_POST` массив, с ключами из имен полей формы

Comment: Спасибо, действительно то, что надо.

Comment: Проблема устранена,еще раз большое спасибо!